# ngModel not working inside a for loop in angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

i am working on an app, I am trying to do a for loop inside a for loop, the for loop will have an input field, and when i edit one of the input field, it will update the value in the array, but my problem is that its updating the whole values instead of the value in the index, 
here is the array

```
newSatas=[{"name":"","freeKG":"","CPMPK":""},{"name":"","freeKG":"","CPMPK":""}{"name":"","freeKG":"","CPMPK":""}]
```

here is the for loop

```
<div *ngFor="let newSata of newSatas; let i=index; trackBy:trackByIndex;">
    <label>Delivery Name 
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newSatas[i].name" name="name[{{i}}]" class="form-control" placeholder="Site Name">
    </label>
    <label>Price Per KiloMeter Per Kg
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newSatas[i].CPMPK" name="CPMPK[{{i}}]" class="form-control" placeholder="Price Per KiloMeter Per Kg">
    </label>
    <label>Free KG
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newSatas[i].freeKG" name="freeKG[{{i}}]" class="form-control" placeholder="Free KG">
    </label>
</div>
```

Pls how can i update only the value in the index instead of the whole values

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the array? It's likely the very same object.

I believe you do something like this:

```
sata = {"name":"","freeKG":"","CPMPK":""}
newSatas = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) newSatas.push(sata);
```

You will need to create a new object with every iteration

```
newSatas = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) newSatas.push({"name":"","freeKG":"","CPMPK":""});
```

Comment: this is how i created my array  shipData={'id':'', 'name':'','freeKG':'','CPMPK':''}
 shipments=[this.shipData]   this.newSatas=[...this.newSatas, this.shipData]

Comment: Yeah that is basically the very same. Since you are using the SAME object everywhere the same object is updated. But you need copies of your object.

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: Try `this.newSatas=[...this.newSatas, {...this.shipData}]`